# Azure AD single sign on "invalid grant code"

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I am facing the following problem:

I have configured an application for single sign on in Azure AD but I get the following error code:

> "{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS65001: The user
>   or administrator has not consented to use the application with I.....
>   Send an interactive authorization request for this user and
>   resource.\r\nTrace ID: .....e"}'"

The permissions are as following:

Permission to other applications:
Windows Azure Active Directory:

- Application Permissions: 0
- Delegated Permissions: 1 = "Sign in and read user profile"

I have tried by clicking the tile in my apps in portal.office.com and by hitting the sign-on url directly. In the latter case I would expect to be redirected to an `office365` page to authenticate myself and continue but instead I get the code above.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try settle on all options in Application Permissions,Delegated Permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did not really helped.